# ImportError: No module named pygtk

Tags: software-installation, pygtk

I installed the deb files of Fpdb (a poker analysis tool); and i downloaded the program.
The problem is that when i try to run it from the terminal i get this: "ImportError: No module named pygtk ";
I tried to re install and update pygtk but i can't solve the problem.

thanks in advance for any suggestion;

c

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How exactly did you try to "install and update pygtk"?

Comment: Motion to re-open, since the answer I gave (and the one pointed to) don't solve the OP's question.

Comment: I am having the same issue, and the answer that is supposed to be a "duplicate" does not help me (I already have the package installed, and continue to get "no module named gtk").

Answer (score 15):

This means the program you are running is looking for a particular python library called pygtk, which allows your program to have a gui. So, to let the program work, you need to install pygtk:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev
```

That *should* do it.

Comment: When i mean install and update the library i mean with the command:   *sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev*    Also to test that i tried to run python on the terminal and when i try to *import pygtk*  from there i get the same error. What should i do?

Comment: You may want to try to look around in /usr/bin/python/Lib/site-packages for the pygtk folder. Is there one?

Comment: There is a gtk-2.0 folder;

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and have python-gtk2-dev installed.

Comment: the last time I installed this package, apt updates complained every time they ran, and I basically had to remove it with a crowbar (manually removing dpkg's index of the package). Now I see ccsm doesn't run without it. Watch out https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/1808979