# Install pygtk on bash on WSL

Tags: bash, python, gtk, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pygtk

`pip install pygtk` does not work and fails with:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
********************************************************************
* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
********************************************************************

----------------------------------------
```

I just know that this will be tagged duplicate, but this is different, it's on WSL. And the solutions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568798/importerror-no-module-named-pygtk) do not work?

How is it this difficult? And where is PyGTK hosted anyway?

Answer (score 1):

from [PyGObject](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

> If you want to write a Python application for GNOME or a Python GUI application using GTK+, then PyGObject is the way to go.

Apparently PyGTK is made available through PyGObject which can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install python-gi python-gi-cairo python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```